# Setup Keras options for LSTM modelling

Tags: python, python-2.7, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to figure out to setup process of forecasting some value. Currently, I can't understand what is issue in below code:

```
        in_neurons = 1
        out_neurons = 1
        hidden_neurons = 20
        nb_features = 9

        # retrieve data
        y_train = train.pop(target).values
        X_train = pd.concat([train[['QTR_HR_START', 'QTR_HR_END', 'HOLIDAY_RANK_', 'SPECIAL_EVENT_RANK_',
                                    'IS_AM', 'IS_TOP_RANKED', 'AWARDS_WINS_ANY', 'YEARS_SINCE_RELEASE']],
                             pd.DataFrame({'DATETIME': pd.DatetimeIndex(train['DATETIME']).astype(np.int64)})])
        X_train = X_train.values

        y_test = test.pop(target).values
        X_test = pd.concat([test[['QTR_HR_START', 'QTR_HR_END', 'HOLIDAY_RANK_', 'SPECIAL_EVENT_RANK_',
                                    'IS_AM', 'IS_TOP_RANKED', 'AWARDS_WINS_ANY', 'YEARS_SINCE_RELEASE']],
             pd.DataFrame({'DATETIME': pd.DatetimeIndex(test['DATETIME']).astype(np.int64)})])
        X_test = X_test.values

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(8, input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], 100, nb_features), activation='softmax')))
        model.add(LSTM(4, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
        model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After running the code, I got an exception:

> raise Exception('The first layer in a Sequential model must '
>   Exception: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.

Please advice where I am wrong

**EDIT1:** I just configured the model as was mentioned in official documentation - http://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_dim=nb_features, input_length=100))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

> Exception: Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (48614, 9)

Comment: I think Keras expects you to split your data into sequences of consecutive data. That is why it expects the input data to have three dimensions. Have a look how the data is prepared in [this tutorial](http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's old, but I'm posting for future use. Keras as input requiers 3D data, as stated in error. It is samples, time steps, features. Despite the fact that you have (48614, 9) Keras takes it as 2D - [samples, features]. In order to fix it, do something like this

```
def reshape_dataset(train):
    trainX = numpy.reshape(train, (train.shape[0], 1, train.shape[1]))
    return numpy.array(trainX)

x = reshape_dataset(your_dataset_48614, 9)
```

now `X` should be `48614,1, 9` which is [samples, time steps, features] - 3D

Comment: You can also use `model.add(RepeatVector(1))`. It will add the extra dimension.